# Cannot display ng-view, enclosed in comment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm developing a single page app using Node, Express, and Angular. My directory is structured like the usual Express apps

```
<app>
  +--public
  +--routes
  +--views
     +--partials
        |--<html files for ng view>
      |--index.html
  |--server.js
  |--package.json
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name" :            "app-name",
    "version" :         "0.0.1",
    "dependencies" : {
        "body-parser"   : "1.9.2",
        "express"       : "4.10.0",
        "method-override": "2.3.1"
    }
}
```

I am using AngularJS for my client-side routing

```
// public/js/app.js

var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config = (['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
                function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' })
        .when('/about', { templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl' })
        .when('/services', { templateUrl: 'partials/services.html', controller: 'ServicesCtrl' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' }) 
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'I\'m the Portal';
});
app.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Wanna know more \'bout me?';
});
app.controller('ServicesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Still gonna serve ya\'!';
});
```

Here's my server.js:

```
// server.js
var express     = require('express');

var app         = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/partials/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.sendFile('views/partials/' + name, { root: __dirname});
    // also tried res.render, what's the difference?
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/views' });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", 
        this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

I am not yet separating into modules the Angular controllers and Express routing. Here's my index.html file:

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div class="container">

        <!--
        <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
        REPLACED BELOW WITH THE CODE ABOVE, AND IT'S WORKING
        -->
        <div class="masthead">
            <h3 class="text-muted"> COMPANY </h3>
            <nav class="nav navbar-default">
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/"> HOME </a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about"> ABOUT </a></li>
                    <li><a href="/services"> SERVICES </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <!-- THIS PART WON'T WORK, IN COMMENT WHEN INSPECTED -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script...></script>
</body>
```

I launch my app using `nodemon`. My problem is I can't seem to see the ng-view portion, but the template (`ng-include`) is working. `ng-view` is in comment when inspected. I already tried looking for other similar questions in SO, but their solution won't work in my case. Can you point out what's wrong with my code?

Is it necessary to use templating engine like Jade (Pug now) or EJS for `ng-view` to work? I prefer to use plain HTML rather than learn a templating engine.

What's the difference with `res.sendFile` and `res.render`? Is `res.render` for templating engine only?

How do I test it by the way? How would I know if Express is sending the partials correctly?

Comment: I think your view is loading. I mean route is not working.

Comment: Can you pleas check by adding, app.run(function($location){$location.url ="/about"})

Comment: @Ved Which route? Angular routing or Express routing? Already tried `app.run`, `ng-view` still in comment.

Comment: Do you see network calls made for html partials in browser console?

Comment: @Muthukannan Only the header.html gets called, no partials getting XHRed.

Comment: did you try like this(with #)? <li><a href="#/about"> ABOUT </a></li>.. since html5Mode is not turned on!

Answer (score 0):

Try and change this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/views' });
});
```

To this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Comment: This results in error. Node.js can't find index.html